# ERROR: Could not build wheels for esmre which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio, pip, pep517

I'm trying to install esmre using `pip install esmre` but got error log:

```
    Building wheel for esmre (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\my\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' 'c:\users\my\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\my\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpyn_e_1fj'
       cwd: C:\Users\my\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d7z9p1pt\esmre_d6ab7ab88a0b46b69217e46e7a6fb9c5      
  Complete output (21 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  copying src\esmre.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  running build_ext
  building 'esm' extension
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src\esm
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\claud\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\claud\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30037\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt 
-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt /Tcsrc/esm.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/esm.obj  esm.c
  src/esm.c(1651): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'ac_offset', possible loss of data
  src/esm.c(1935): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'ac_offset', possible loss of data
  src/esm.c(2386): error C2039: 'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'
 '_typeobject'
  src/esm.c(2892): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3
  src/esm.c(2908): warning C4996: '_PyUnicode_get_wstr_length': deprecated in 3.3
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30037\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for esmre
Failed to build esmre
ERROR: Could not build wheels for esmre which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Here's my specification:

- Windows 10 home 64 bit
- Python 3.9.5
- pip 21.1.3

I have tried:

- Upgrade pip and setuptools
- `python -m pip install --no-use-pep517 esmre`
- `pip install esmre --no-binary :all:`
- install esmre with the setup.py inside the package.
- `pip install pep517`

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Can you try `pip install pep517`

Comment: @SaatvikRamani just tried but the error persist, thanks though!

Comment: The real error is "**'tp_print': is not a member of '_typeobject'**"

Comment: The code was not updated in a year. It requires Python <= 3.8. Downgrade to Python 3.8 and try again.